# Can't work out promises to return values - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

After searching through countless posts I don't understand why I'm still getting a Promise pending after my awaits. The code below should explain it but I'm trying to pull a MongoDB query of the max value of a column/schema. The console.log within the function is giving me the correct timestamp but I'm trying to pass that out of the inner scope and function to another function.

This is pure NodeJS with only MongoDB imported. Can this be done without any external packages?

```
    export async function getMaxDate() {
        var time = MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            var dbo = db.db(getDB);
            dbo.collection(getColl)
                .find()
                .limit(1)
                .sort({ 'timestamp': -1 })
                .toArray(function (err, result) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    time = result[0].time; // THIS IS GIVING THE CORRECT VALUE
                    console.log(time)
                    db.close();
                });

        });
        return time    
    }

    export async function getMax() {
        var block = await getMaxDate();
        return block
    } 

    var t = getMax();
    console.log(t); // THIS IS GIVE ME A PROMISE PENDING
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getMax()` returns a promise, you have to wait for it.

```
var t = await getMax()
```

Also `getMaxDate` uses an async callback that you want to promisify:

```js
export async function getMaxDate() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {  
    MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
      if (err)
        return reject(err);
      var dbo = db.db(getDB);
      dbo.collection(getColl)
        .find()
        .limit(1)
        .sort({ 'timestamp': -1 })
        .toArray(function (err, result) {
          if(err)
            reject(err);
          else {
            let time = result[0].time; // THIS IS GIVING THE CORRECT VALUE
            console.log(time)
            db.close();
            resolve(time);
          }
        });
    })
  });
}
```

For reference, A is the same thing as B here:

```js
async function A(x) {
  if(x)
    throw new Error('foo');
  else
    return 'bar';
}
function B(x) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    if(x)
      reject(new Error('foo'));
    else
      resolve('bar');
  });
}
```

Promises came first, then async/await notation was introduced to make common Promise coding practices easier

You can use A and B interchangeably:

```
async function example1() {
  try { 
    await A(1);
    await B(0);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log('got error from A');
  }
}
async function example2() {
  return A(0).then(()=>B(1)).catch((err)=>{
    console.log('got error from B');
  })
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thanks for taking the time out to help! I thought the Promise was already happening as part of the function but wrapping it all in like you suggested works great!